# Understanding Event-Driving Programming Style

Tags: javascript, event-driven

Looking for this example (and with my previous knowledge's in event-driven). I can say that this two routines run independently and in parallel (so will not block the hole program).

```
//....declaration and methods
register_1.on("execut_routine _1", function() { console.log("executed the routine  1"):})
register_2.on("execut_routine _2", function() { console.log("executed the routine  2"):})
```

But if i make this change:

```
//....declaration and methods
register_1.on("execut_routine _1", function() { /*Long Blocking Operation*/})
register_2.on("execut_routine _2", function() { /*Long Blocking Operation*/})
```

The first triggered event will block the happening of the second, right? If so, How can I reverse that effect?

Comment: The two routines in your first example will **not** run in parallel. They will run sequentially. You might want to look into the "JavaScript event loop". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop is a good starting point.

Comment: @Matt I think  routine_1 and routine_2 run in parallel. But the "end event" of this routines run sequentially. No? My objective is to not block in the event callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is a single-threaded environment, so unless you are doing input/output related tasks (waiting on the file system, calling an external resource, etc), your code must wait for other code to finish.

Using event-driven programming styles will *not* help you with this problem.

However, you can tell your code to go into a sort of "sleep" mode, where it waits for other code to execute, and begins again at the next tick of the event loop.  Node.js, for example, uses `process.nextTick(fn)` to register code that should execute over multiple ticks.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is [generally] not a multi-threaded environment and so even in your first example, the reality is that they execute serially and not in parallel.  Thinks like XHR's run in parallel, but they run as a function of the browser and not Javascript directly (i.e. the network requests run in parallel), but the javascript handlers will always fire serially.